# show dialog when application/activity startup

Tags: android, dialog

can we show the dialog when our appliaction/activity startup?

Comment: And you should make your question more specific and not just an exact copy of the title. What dialog do you want to show? You mean only when your application starts for the first time? Every time your application starts? We need more information

Comment: Just reposting the question in the post doesn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can show a dialog, look on the answer [Displaying alerts in Activity.onCreate(..)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509391/displaying-alerts-in-activity-oncreate/3509503#3509503)

Comment: in my application i am doing some database side functionality
i get all data from the xml file that is placed on some server...
and store those data on database...after that i am showing the data on screen...Here single activity do all of the work(load data from url,store the data and show the data on screen)...so that activity take sometimes to finish all the process...at that time screen show as blank...i want to show the dialog or progress on that screen...
can we do this?

Comment: You need to implement AsyncTask then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490674/observer-pattern-in-android/3490807#3490807 look at the example.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at AsynTask. Amongst others there are three methods which can serve your requirement.

onPreExecute, onPostExetcute and doInBackground;

start the progress dialog in onPreExecute
dismiss the progress dialog in onPostExetcute 
do you connection in doInBackground.

Hope that will serve your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.droidnova.com/how-to-create-a-splash-screen,561.html

There appears to be lost of information on this - just [Google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=android+splash+screen+&aq=f&aqi=g6&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) it.

Comment: in my application i am doing some database side functionality
i get all data from the xml file that is placed on some server...
and store those data on database...after that i am showing the data on screen...Here single activity do all of the work(load data from url,store the data and show the data on screen)...so that activity take sometimes to finish all the process...at that time screen show as blank...i want to show the dialog or progress on that screen...
can we do this?

Answer (score 0):

try this way
in post execute display your database from database. and pre execute start dialog and post execute close it. if you want to show horizontal incrementing progress bar then in do in backgrond put that code that i have there.

> private class DownloadImageTask
>   extends AsyncTask
>   {
>
> protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
>
> ```
>           while (myProgress<length){
>                  myProgress=myProgress+1;  
>                  myProgressBar.setProgress(myProgress);
>
>           }
>            return decodeImage(urls[0]);
>       }
>
>       protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
>           dialog.dismiss();
>           imView.setImageBitmap(result);
>       }           protected void onPreExecute() {
>   // Things to be done while execution of long running operation is
>            in progress. For example updating
>              ProgessDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(BusinessCardActivity.this,
>             "Loading.........", "Wait For Few Second", true);             }
>   }
> ```